# Python Dataframe filling up non existing

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I was wondering if there is an efficient way to add rows to a Dataframe that e.g. include the average or a predifined value in case there are not enough rows for a specific value in another column. I guess the description of the Problem is not the best that is why you find an example below:
Say we have the Dataframe

```
df1
Client NumberOfProducts ID
A      1                2
A      5                1
B      1                2
B      6                1
C      9                1
```

And we want to have 2 Rows for each client A, B, C, D, no matter if these 2 rows are already existing or not. So for Client A and B we can just copy the rows, for C we want to add a row which says Client = C, NumberOfProducts = average of existing rows = 9 and ID is not of interest (so we could set it to ID = smallest existing one - 1 = 0 any other value, even NaN, would also be possible). For Client D there does not exist a single row so we want to add 2 rows where NumberOfProducts is equal to the constant 2.5. The output should then look like this:

```
df1
Client NumberOfProducts ID
A      1                2
A      5                1
B      1                2
B      6                1
C      9                1
C      9                0
D      2.5              NaN
D      2.5              NaN
```

What I have done so far is to loop through the dataframe and add rows where necessary. Since this is pretty inefficient any better solution would be highly appreciated.

Comment: There are always maximal 2 values per each Client? Or possible more?

Comment: Related to the example there would always be a maximum of 2 rows. In the real world it would not be 2 but a number that is already known/entered by the user (e.g. 10, 15 etc.).

Comment: ok, so it means `.groupby('Client').head(2)` should be omit from my solution?

Comment: I have used the exact same statement to get the dataframe from the original data, just that i would not enter the number 2 but any number.

Comment: Ok, so changed `.head(N)` in my solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
clients = ['A','B','C','D']
N = 2

#test only values from list and also filter only 2 rows for each client if necessary
df = df[df['Client'].isin(clients)].groupby('Client').head(N)

#create helper counter and reshape by unstack
df1 = df.set_index(['Client',df.groupby('Client').cumcount()]).unstack()
#set first if only 1 row per client - replace second NumberOfProducts by first 
df1[('NumberOfProducts',1)] = df1[('NumberOfProducts',1)].fillna(df1[('NumberOfProducts',0)])
# ... replace second ID by first subtracted by 1
df1[('ID',1)] = df1[('ID',1)].fillna(df1[('ID',0)] - 1)
#add missing clients by reindex
df1 = df1.reindex(clients)
#replace NumberOfProducts by constant 2.5
df1['NumberOfProducts'] = df1['NumberOfProducts'].fillna(2.5)
print (df1)
       NumberOfProducts        ID     
                      0    1    0    1
Client                                
A                   1.0  5.0  2.0  1.0
B                   1.0  6.0  2.0  1.0
C                   9.0  9.0  1.0  0.0
D                   2.5  2.5  NaN  NaN
```

---

```
#last reshape to original
df2 = df1.stack().reset_index(level=1, drop=True).reset_index()
print (df2)
  Client  NumberOfProducts   ID
0      A               1.0  2.0
1      A               5.0  1.0
2      B               1.0  2.0
3      B               6.0  1.0
4      C               9.0  1.0
5      C               9.0  0.0
6      D               2.5  NaN
7      D               2.5  NaN
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have replaced df1[('NumberOfProducts',1)] = df1[('NumberOfProducts',1)].fillna(df1[('NumberOfProducts',0)]) by df1[('NumberOfProducts',1)] = df1[('NumberOfProducts',1)].T.fillna(df1[('NumberOfProducts',0)].mean(axis = 1)).T so that the mean of the NumberOfProducts is used instead of the last entry and now it works perfectly.